# Optimize Union Find (Disjoint Set Union) implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, disjoint-sets, union-find

I have implemented a Disjoint Set Union in C++ for a [Kattis problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/unionfind). However, my solution is inefficient, as I get TLA (Time Limit Exceeded) for the first hidden test case. Can anyone spot an inefficiency with my code?

I have based my implementation on [this article](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/disjoint_set_union.html). In particular, I set the parent of the parent of the smaller set to the parent of the bigger set (when making an union of the sets). According to the mentioned article, this should be as efficient as using the rank:

> Both optimizations are equivalent in terms of time and space complexity. So in practice you can use any of them.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vi;

class UnionFind {
private:
  vi p;
  vi size;

public:
  UnionFind(int N) {
    p.assign(N, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
      p[i] = i;
    size.assign(N, 1);
  }

  int findSet(int i) { return (p[i] == i) ? i : (p[i] = findSet(p[i])); }

  bool isSameSet(int i, int j) { return findSet(i) == findSet(j); }

  void unionSet(int i, int j) {
    int x = findSet(i);
    int y = findSet(j);
    if (x == y)
      return;
    if (size[x] < size[y])
      swap(x, y);
    p[y] = x;
    size[x] += size[y];
  }
};

int main() {
  int n;
  int q;
  cin >> n >> q;
  auto set = UnionFind(n);
  while (q--) {
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    int x;
    int y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    if (ch == '=') {
      set.unionSet(x, y);
    } else if (ch == '?') {
      if (set.isSameSet(x, y))
        cout << "yes" << endl;
      else
        cout << "no" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a Kattis-specific IO problem. Adding `ios::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL); cout.tie(NULL);` to the start of main, and changing both occurrences of `endl` to `'\n'` causes it to pass in .2 seconds.

I'll also mention that [including `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/16757174) is frowned upon here, but the only cause of your error was the IO. Your implementation of Union Find is correct and runs in the standard inverse Ackermann time bounds.

Comment: Ahh, good to know. I read the code and the Union Find seemed correct to me with path compression. I had a hunch that it's an IO problem but I'm not very familiar with C++. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @user1984 It wasn't at all obvious, only found it after removing all other possibilities. I really thought that there was an infinite loop; my advice to OP is avoid risking infinite loops with things like `while (q--)` on online judges where both the input and output of a program is hidden from you.

Comment: Thank you! I will report the first as a bug. And I didn't expect that `std:endl` would make such a big difference, but I should know better. Also, the 'hack' with the header is actually a recommended practice in competitive programming (but obviously not in software engineering).